# concrete grooving

Tags: concrete

I am looking to put radiant heating in my garage floor.  I am looking for some sort of grinder wheel to cut 3/4inch U shaped grooves in the floor for the pex tube. Or would it be easier to cut 2-3 thin cuts and chip it all out?
Maybe something like a router?
Thanks
Thomas

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This sounds like a great way to trash your garage slab.

Comment: The tool which might do the job for you is one I've sen used when remodeling houses with brick (solid) walls to run new electrical cabling. It's a grinder with 2 cutting disks mounted on the shaft with a spacer between so that it makes 2 parallel cuts in one go. You do still have to chip the masonry out between them afterwards, but it does make a nice neat channel.

Comment: I think I would want to do an overlay instead of cutting groves in the slab. If the slab is only 4" thick taking out 3/4" will severely weaken it. An overlay will not affect the strength but be quicker and lest costly.

Comment: I'd much rather put in some other form of heat than go through all that time and trouble. +1 for Ed's suggestion if you want to stick to the floor.

Comment: Is the slab insulated underneath? If not, expect a disappointing (or at least expensive to run) radiant heat experience regardless of how you get the tubes in, unless you have sufficient headroom to lay insulation and a new slab on top of the old slab.